# Unexpected x axis tick marks when using bar chart in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a bar chart in ggplot that shows the profit in two separate locations on specific days.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
test_data <- data.frame("location" = c('location_1', 'location_2',
                                   'location_1', 'location_2',
                                   'location_1', 'location_2',
                                   'location_1', 'location_2',
                                   'location_1', 'location_2',
                                   'location_1', 'location_2',
                                   'location_1', 'location_2',
                                   'location_1', 'location_2',
                                   'location_1', 'location_2'), 
                      "date" = c(as.Date('2018-07-29'), as.Date('2018-07-29'), 
                               as.Date('2018-07-30'), as.Date('2018-07-30'), 
                               as.Date('2018-08-02'), as.Date('2018-08-02'), 
                               as.Date('2018-08-03'), as.Date('2018-08-03'), 
                               as.Date('2018-08-05'), as.Date('2018-08-05'),
                               as.Date('2018-08-08'), as.Date('2018-08-08'),
                               as.Date('2018-08-12'), as.Date('2018-08-12'), 
                               as.Date('2018-08-15'), as.Date('2018-08-15'), 
                               as.Date('2018-08-19'), as.Date('2018-08-19')),
                    "profit" = c(540, 120, 265, 493, 245, 432, 987, 566,
                                 654, 765, 234, 767, 650, 765, 874, 652,
                                 175, 497), 
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

sundays <- c(as.Date('2018-07-29'),as.Date('2018-08-05'),
             as.Date('2018-08-12'),as.Date('2018-08-19'))

test_data %>% 
filter(date %in% sundays) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=date, y=profit)) + 
geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
xlab('Date') +
ylab('Profit') + 
facet_wrap(~location)
```

So I want to create a graph that only displays the Sundays however, when it's plotted it associates the wrong dates with the bars.

[image: graph example]

How do I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: scale_x_date() plus specify the breaks! cheers

Comment: ggplot will use dates and create a date axis, so what it is doing is giving you the full range that you indicated, divided equally.  I would look into leaving the dates as strings and trying to specify the index from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this solution:

```
test_data %>%
  filter(date %in% sundays) %>%
  mutate(date = date %>% as.character()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=date, y=profit)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  xlab('Date') +
  ylab('Profit') + 
  facet_wrap(~location) +
  scale_x_discrete(
    labels = function(x) x %>% as.Date() %>% format('%b %d')
  )
```

#### Answer to question in comment:

I figured out some "dirty hack" but I'm not sure if it will work in all cases. Check and let me know.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(wrapr)

test_data %>%
  filter(date %in% sundays) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  group_by(location) %>%
  mutate(
    xpos = row_number(),
    xlab = if_else(xpos %% 2 == 0, '', date %>% as.Date() %>% format('%b %d'))
  ) %.>%
  ggplot(
    data = .,
    aes(x = factor(xpos), y = profit)
  ) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  xlab('Date') +
  ylab('Profit') + 
  facet_wrap(~location) +
  scale_x_discrete(
    breaks = .$xpos,
    labels = .$xlab 
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was really helpful. I have created a similar graph where I have dates on the x-axis however, I only want to include the date for every second bar (for example) as there are too many and it looks messy. I was going to use this scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "2 day") however, I can't have two scales for x. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @plshelp I've eddited my answer. Check if it's working.